# Is this kind of question allowed on SO?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ask for opinions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67213/how-to-ask-for-opinions)

I would like to get information about what development platforms people are using. It's development related, non-argumentative, non-subjective etc etc. And is programming related.

But I got close voted twice already without any explanation.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/3904860/75642

I was also thinking of any other SE site that would be more appropriate for this, but I don't think there is one. Is it? Should I better reformulate my question to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kind of subjective, there is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question.

Comment: this is the right answer. programmers is full of discussions

Answer (score 2):

Your post is a poll (or survey), not a question:

- It cannot have a single answer.
- It reinvents the rules - over 90% of your post explains how to vote on *this post*.
- It explains why the post is ok - a clear giveaway it isn't `:)`

A better question would be "any real data on use of these frameworks?" - e.g., asking for results of the survey you've requested, without actually conducting it on SO, and preferably on a limited scope (specific industry/big sites/open source/etc)

Comment: Additional info has been added later for those voters-to-close that don't really read the question. And there are quite many arrogant developers like that in SO community. But you're right with the first two.