# Looking for a site/app/etc

Tags: feature-request

I see lots of posts closed where people are just looking for opinions on the best site or an app that does x.  Maybe a new community for these types of questions?  I've tried asking these questions myself a couple times, but more importantly for SE, I've encountered them via Google searches.  It would be beneficial to SE if I found an answer instead of a closed topic.

Comment: Those questions simply don't belong on the site. They are off-topic and should be closed, if not deleted.

Comment: Wow, did you even read my post?

Comment: @ScottBeeson They don't belong on the network, at all; we don't want questions like that. See for example [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67215/145982)

Comment: @ScottBeeson Yes, I did. There is not any site on the network which would support such a question or the format. Nor would such a site ever be created for it, given earlier discussions on similar subjects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community has come to the decision that such questions cause too many problems, and don't provide enough value to be allowed on *any* Stack Exchange site.  The reasons are described in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Some of the main points:

- They tend to attract lots of spam answers where everyone just posts a link to their product and moves on; it's rare to see real analysis of products or honest, detailed information.
- They are highly localized.  The best product today is unlikely to be the best product a year from now.  This means constant updating of questions, or constant re-asking, both of which have a high "cost" to the community.
- There is no good objective measure of what the "correct" answer is.

Comment: Thank you for a reasonable answer.

Comment: Do you any site to replace SE in this kind of questions?