# How to ask for help finding resources

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask for help finding resources regarding a particular programming language.

I realize that Stack Exchange is designed to be more of a hunter and less of a gatherer; it is meant to be very specific. If I ask a question that is not intended to objectively elicit "the right answer" then what forum should I post that question to? Is there one at all?

In my case I am looking for information to help get started with [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) and feel that I am having a hard time finding resources. I believe that the SE community could point me in the right direction, but I want to be sure that I ask in the appropriate place.

[This topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67213/how-to-ask-for-opinions) suggests that I use [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) to ask for "opinions", but the [Programmers SE FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) states the following:

> "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Now, I feel that my question will be practical and indeed answerable; it's even based on actual problems that I am facing... But my question will not be specific enough to elicit a single "AHA! This is the answer!" - it won't be meant to do that. When I'm done asking, I hope that my question will have several answers from several different people and that it will be useful as a resource for someone else in the same position as me.

Is Programmer's SE the place to do that? Or should I be looking elsewhere? Should I entirely leave the SE family of sites and find forums related to the topic somewhere else?

Comment: Have you already looked at the tag wiki for T-SQL? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info

Comment: Rob - thank you! I have looked at it. I am *entirely* green and I started by looking at wikipedia this morning. I don't mean for this question to turn into my actual question, but thank you for your comment :)

Comment: I keep thinking that the sharp focus of SO makes for some interesting opportunities: Whenever there is something that SO is _not_, somebody else could make a site which does that. Community maintained lists of resources and tutorials would be a very useful thing, if done right.

Comment: @Monolo As I mentioned to Bart, would a community wiki fit that bill? I don't know if it might end up being too broad, but it seems like a wiki page dedicated to the *best* resources for a particular language or tool might come in handy. And perhaps even saying "best" resources is too subjective...

Comment: Wikis are useful, but I can't tell if they fit the bill enough to make a difference. Anyway, my comment was a general reflection on SO's sharp focus and how it can be seen as a generator of opportunities rather than a restriction :-)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the top answer on the duplicate target does not address the question of where to ask for resources (it suggests looking through the list of SE sites for a related site, when most sites don't like these sorts of questions, and the other highly upvoted one implies the same).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I entirely leave the SE family of sites and find forums related to the topic somewhere else?

This.

Asking for links or references to resources is not an appropriate question on *any* of SE's Q/A sites.

Comment: Ho, stop, don't leave @chris! Perhaps leave for a while to ask your resource question, but please stay for the on-topic ones. :)

Comment: @Bart Is there perhaps a community wiki that could be set up for something like this? I'd hate to see little noobs like me running away in horror as they are downvoted again and again and again :)

Comment: @Chris Tag wikis are an excellent way to list such sources. For example, check the tag wikis of [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), [C](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), [C++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info), [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info), [Android](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info). As you can see, all of them link to (useful) (learning) resources.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the suggestion! I just pulled up the info page for TSQL and downloaded the Sybase user's manual. Quite the read... lol! I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: RPG.SE fields resource questions. They appear to work well in that domain. This answer is making an inaccurate generalisation.

Comment: @doppelgreener adressed that in an edit

Comment: @Servy I updated your answer based on the comments here and my knowledge as this question got reopened

Comment: @Luuklag The question asks where they can ask about eternal resources on how to get started programming with TSQL.  **For that question** neither of those sites are appropriate.  The question does not ask about questions asking about *any* type of external resource.

Comment: Haha how time flies. Odds are that most of the answers to this question of mine are far easier to find these days than they were 8 years ago. But the answer here is still valid! I've found other communities to ask my more vague questions to. Generally speaking there is more technical information on the internet than there used to be, even back in 2013.