# I'm trying to find a video - Who should I ask?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The Stack Exchange network seems like the best way to get good answers fast, but I don't if and what SE forum I should use to ask my question:

> I'm looking for somewhere, **anywhere**, that would let me view and or purchase the **full** taping of the September 20th, 1973 tennis match between Billy Jean King and Bobby Riggs, also known as "The Battle of the Sexes".
>
> I just need evidence that it exists **somewhere** so I can go about trying to obtain it. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Sports Stack Exchange](https://sports.stackexchange.com/). <s>Based on their [On Topic](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page and their [Determining our scope](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156) meta topic, I'm *inclined* to think it's on topic there, but there's a possibility it isn't.</s>

You could ask on their meta for them to advise you on whether it's on topic or not, or you could just go ahead and ask it there and find out (via it being left open or closed).

Unfortunately: they [don't permit video questions](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216/closing-of-my-question-about-finding-a-video-of-a-sporting-event):

> The fact of the matter is that we are not here to do this kind of research for you. We are here to provide you answers to questions you have about sports, either playing in them, watching them, the rules, and sometimes some trivia surrounding them. Sports broadcasting is even on topic.
>
> However, what you really want is someone to run a google search to find video of a long past sporting event. That's not constructive under any definition of the term. It's something you can easily do yourself. If you haven't found it yourself (and I'm assuming you've looked from the context of your question) then it's probably not findable by anyone on this site.

Since the one place this would be on-topic has determined this is off-topic, you will probably need to hunt this down yourself.

Comment: mhhhmm I'm not sure ... from the On Topics: Some kinds of questions should NOT be asked here: Requests for sources/research

Comment: @bummi That is exactly the line that makes me hesitate.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178064

Comment: @bummi That answer is making an inaccurate generalisation. RPG.SE, for instance, fields resource questions. They appear to work well in that domain.

Comment: You might be right, I already had similar assessment fails on other pages. It is certainly useful to study the special ON / OFF topics of the different sites.

Comment: As a moderator on Sports SE, I can confirm the comment made by @bummi that asking for a video is off-topic on Sports SE by the verbiage referenced. Here is more Sports SE meta discussion about requests for research/sources: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/216/closing-of-my-question-about-finding-a-video-of-a-sporting-event

Comment: @edmastermind29 Thanks, I've updated my answer to reflect that.